# Is there any method to reduce code in conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to reduce my code in above image to something in short in conditional statements. In this i am trying to convert BHK in integer value to use it in Machine Learning.

```
def replace_size(string):
    if string == '1 RK':
        return 0
    elif string == '1 BHK' or string == '1 Bedroom':
        return 1
    elif string == '2 BHK' or string == '2 Bedroom':
        return 2
    elif string == '3 BHK' or string == '3 Bedroom':
        return 3
    elif string == '4 BHK' or string == '4 Bedroom':
        return 4
    elif string == '5 BHK' or string == '5 Bedroom':
        return 5
    elif string == '6 BHK' or string == '6 Bedroom':
        return 6
    elif string == '7 BHK' or string == '7 Bedroom':
        return 7
    elif string == '8 BHK' or string == '8 Bedroom':
        return 8
    elif string == '9 BHK' or string == '9 Bedroom':
        return 9
    elif string == '10 BHK' or string == '10 Bedroom':
        return 10
    elif string == '11 BHK' or string == '11 Bedroom':
        return 11
    elif string == '12 BHK' or string == '12 Bedroom':
        return 12
    elif string == '13 BHK' or string =='13 Bedroom':
        return 13
    elif string == '14 BHK' or string =='14 Bedroom':
        return 14
    elif string == '16 BHK' or string =='16 Bedroom':
        return 16
    elif string == '18 BHK' or string =='18 Bedroom':
        return 18
    elif string == '19 BHK' or string =='19 Bedroom':
        return 19
    elif string == '27 BHK' or string =='27 Bedroom':
        return 27
    elif string == '43 BHK' or string =='43 Bedroom':
        return 43
```

I trying to use pandas series which contain '1 Bedroom', '1 BHK' and '1 RK' then use apply(replace_size) function on series to get pandas series of int type value.

Thanks1

Comment: just try to parse a number out from the beginning, and have an explicit statement to handle the first case

Comment: You can also define a dictionary, because you are simulating key lookup in some sense.

Comment: I am trying to put pandas series which '1 Bedroom' , '1 BHK' then use apply(replace_size) to get the following output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def replace_size(string):
    if string == '1 RK':
        return 0
    else:
        st = string.split(' ')
        return int(st[0]) if  (st[1] == "BHK" or  st[1] == "Bedroom") else None
```

Comment: I trying to use pandas series which contain '1 Bedroom', '1 BHK' and '1 RK' then use apply(replace_size) function on series to get pandas series of int type value.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar add the codewhich you are using pandas to call this function

Comment: This is the code which i am using to call the function `train['size'] = train['size'].apply(replace_size)` Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! @Prudhvi it's working now actually I had some Missing value in the column.  After handling the missing column code is working.  Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea, maybe you could use something like:

```
def replace_size(string):
    if string == '1 RK':
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range(1, 44):
            if str(i) in string:
                return i
```

Its probably by far not the best answer, but maybe it will guide you in the right direction.
Also I dont know your possible data and if there are any numbers higher than your mentioned 43 that can occur.

Comment: But won't this return `3` for a string such as "43 BHK", because it checks `"3" in string` before it checks `"43" in string`?

Comment: Yep, you are completly right... Didnt think of that :D As I said just a quick idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


def replace_size(string):
    if string == '1 RK':
        return 0
    elif re.match("\d{1,2} BHK|\d{1,2} Bedroom", string):
        return int(string.split(' ')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a dictionary once:

```
d = {'1 RK':0}
for n in range(1,44):
    d[f'{n} BHK']=n
    d[f'{n} Bedroom']=n

>>> d['5 Bedroom']
5
```

If you need a *callable*

```
def f(s,d=d):
    return d[s]

>>> f('5 Bedroom')
5
```

or

```
class D(dict):
    def __call__(self,key):
        return self[key]

d = D({'1 RK':0})
for n in range(1,44):
    d[f'{n} BHK']=n
    d[f'{n} Bedroom']=n

>>> d('21 Bedroom')
21
```

---

Split the string, check if it is valid; return the result.

```
def g(s):
    a,b = s.split(maxsplit=1)
    if b in ('BHK','Bedroom'):
        value = int(a)
    elif b == 'RK':
        value = 0
    else:
        raise ValueError
    return value


>>> g('1 RK')
0
>>> g('23 Bedroom')
23
>>> g('32 Foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    g('32 Foo')
  File "C:\pyProjects33\tmp.py", line 45, in g
    raise ValueError
ValueError
>>>
```

---

Construct matching strings in a loop:

```
def f(s):
    if s == '1 RK':
        return 0
    for n in range(1,44):
        if s in (f'{n} BHK',f'{n} Bedroom'):
            return n
```